# Find the projection of a vector on a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

> Let $W$ be a subspace in $R^n$ where
> $$ 
> W = s \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\0\\2\\ \end{bmatrix}
> + t \begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}. 
> $$
> Determine the orthogonal projection of $v = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\3 \end{bmatrix}$ onto $W$.

What I did was find a vector that is orthogonal to both the linearly independent vectors, kind of like a normal which ended up being a combination of $2$ vectors when solving a matrix.

I got
$$
n = \frac13 \begin{bmatrix} -2\\-4\\3\\3 \end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then I projected the vector $v$ onto the normal and got the vector $w$. Then I did
$$
v - w = \frac{3}{38} \begin{bmatrix} 2\\-4\\3\\261\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
This was wrong tho, so I wonder why this method doesn't work? Help me find another way but I'd really like to know why this method didn't work either like it usually does in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so I know when not to use it.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^4$, the vector $n$ that is orthogonal to the vectors in $W$ is NOT unique. For example, $$n=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\3\\0\end{bmatrix} \quad m=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ are linearly independent and both are orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: How come? It is kind of hard to get a picture in my head of something in 4D.

Comment: Why is there a $1/3$ in front of $n$? Is it in order to get $\|n\|=1$? If so, $1/3$ is not the correct factor.

Comment: Typo in my comment: $$m=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}.$$ Think of it this way, your subspace $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $2-$dimensional, so it's orthogonal complement $W^{\perp}$ (null space of an appropriate transformation) will be $4-2=2$ dimensional.

Comment: No that is just the vector I got, written like tv where v is a vector.

Comment: @KibMe Perhaps you may want to look into http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Projection_onto_Subspaces or Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: OKAY so what I did was sum up the two linearly independent vectors I got for the normal which I admit now sounds stupid. Anways does this mean this will not work for $R^n$ where n>3 or it just means that in order for it to work like you said the nullspace needs to be of one dimension?

Comment: @KibMe For the particular process the way you have done it, the space must be one dimensional.

Comment: Yeah I've a question about gram-schmidt method tho, when we project the vector. The vectors in W need to be orthogonal right? Or just in general when projecting a vector onto a plane , in order to use gram-schmidt you need to rewrite the plane with orthogonal vectors right?

Comment: So it means that the method I used is not just for $R^3$ and it could work for other $R^n$?

Comment: As I was using gram-schmidt I got a really complicated fractions when making $w_2 = 1/6 [13, -5, 6,-4]$. The problem starts when I keep working with it and the number get big really fast. When I checked the answers they give a hint to multiply it by 6. I don't fully understand y, but is it because when we later project the vector $v$ onto $w_2$, it doesn't really matter how long or short $w_2$ is since the length of the projection will be the same no matter what. It makes a perfect sense but I just have to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this reference](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/algebra/linear-algebra/real-euclidean-vector-spaces/projection-onto-a-subspace)

Basically the steps are:

1. Find $\{w_1, w_2\}$ - an orthonormal basis of $W$
2. Then, $ v' = (v \cdot w_1)w_1 + (v \cdot w_2)w_2$ will be the orthogonal projection

Comment: You have a typo in step 2, as the expression on the right is a scalar.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks for catching!.

Comment: Do they need to be orthonormal? Isn't orthogonal enough?

Comment: @KibMe If you do orthogonal you'll need to normalize in step 2.